# SQL->Informix DB Linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssms

I was unable to create a linked server from SQL server 2014 to Informix. 
Here what I have Done:

> Installed the latest Informix OBDC Driver on the SQL server host machine.
>   Confiugured a system DNS for the IBM Informix ODBC(32bit) driver setup.
>   Tested the connectivity of the DNS setting(test is good).
>   ----Attempted to create the linked server

```
DECLARE @provider NVARCHAR(4000);  
SET @provider = N'Driver={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER};'  
  + N'DATABASE=abc;'     --Informix DB name    
  + N'HOST=xxx.xxx.xx ;'         --Informix Hostname or IP adddress
  + N'SERVICE=1504 ;'         --Informix service name, ex.  ifx1_tcp1
  + N'PROTOCOL=onsoctcp;'      --Informix protocol, ex.  onsoctcp
  + N'SERVER=abcx;'               --Informix server, ex. ifx1
  + N'DB_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8; CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8;'; --Change to your locale, as needed

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'abcx', --Linked Server system name
@srvproduct=N'Ifxoledbc', 
@provider=N'MSDASQL', 
@datasrc=N'ucxxprimary', --Your System DSN Name
@provstr= @provider;
```

Failed with following error:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"
>   for linked server "abcx". OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server
>   "abcx" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The
>   specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and
>   Application". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

Comment: I had a tough time with this a while back and posted [a lot of info in my question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171204/sql-server-informix-db-linked-server), and got a great solution on dba.stackexchange.com that may be able to help. )

Comment: @scsimon: I'm getting different error:  The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

Comment: Can u please send or attach the screenshot linked server please. @scsimon